# How to spot gaps between pandas dataframe indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This code creates an dataframe with 10 minute range index:

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 

date_range = pd.date_range(end=dt.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 15, 00), periods=10, freq='10Min')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)
df['A'] = 1

print(df)
```

It outputs:

```
                     A
2017-01-06 13:30:00  1
2017-01-06 13:40:00  1
2017-01-06 13:50:00  1
2017-01-06 14:00:00  1
2017-01-06 14:10:00  1
2017-01-06 14:20:00  1
2017-01-06 14:30:00  1
2017-01-06 14:40:00  1
2017-01-06 14:50:00  1
2017-01-06 15:00:00  1
```

My question is:

How may I set A column to 0 in the following three rows when there is a gap between the indexes?

For example, if we delete an specific row:

```
df = df[df.index != dt.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 14, 00)]
```

It outputs:

```
                     A
2017-01-06 13:30:00  1
2017-01-06 13:40:00  1
2017-01-06 13:50:00  1
2017-01-06 14:10:00  1
2017-01-06 14:20:00  1
2017-01-06 14:30:00  1
2017-01-06 14:40:00  1
2017-01-06 14:50:00  1
2017-01-06 15:00:00  1
```

Now, there is a missing 10 minute range before 13:50, so the following 3 A rows must be setted to 0.

So this would be the desired result:

```
                     A
2017-01-06 13:30:00  1
2017-01-06 13:40:00  1
2017-01-06 13:50:00  1
2017-01-06 14:10:00  0
2017-01-06 14:20:00  0
2017-01-06 14:30:00  0
2017-01-06 14:40:00  1
2017-01-06 14:50:00  1
2017-01-06 15:00:00  1
```

There is a python fiddle so you can try: https://repl.it/FaXZ/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
#get mask where difference
mask = df.index.to_series().diff() > pd.Timedelta('00:10:00')
#get position of index where True in mask
idx = mask.idxmax()
pos = df.index.get_loc(idx)
#add values by position
df.A.iloc[pos:pos + 2] = 0
print (df)
                     A
2017-01-06 13:30:00  1
2017-01-06 13:40:00  1
2017-01-06 13:50:00  1
2017-01-06 14:10:00  0
2017-01-06 14:20:00  0
2017-01-06 14:30:00  1
2017-01-06 14:40:00  1
2017-01-06 14:50:00  1
2017-01-06 15:00:00  1
```

---

```
df.A.iloc[pos:pos + 5] = 0
print (df)
                     A
2017-01-06 13:30:00  1
2017-01-06 13:40:00  1
2017-01-06 13:50:00  1
2017-01-06 14:10:00  0
2017-01-06 14:20:00  0
2017-01-06 14:30:00  0
2017-01-06 14:40:00  0
2017-01-06 14:50:00  0
2017-01-06 15:00:00  1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = df.index.to_series().diff() > pd.Timedelta('00:10:00')
df['A'] = 1- (temp | temp.shift(1)).astype(int)
```

will result in

```
                     A
2017-01-06 13:30:00  1
2017-01-06 13:40:00  1
2017-01-06 13:50:00  1
2017-01-06 14:10:00  0
2017-01-06 14:20:00  0
2017-01-06 14:30:00  1
2017-01-06 14:40:00  1
2017-01-06 14:50:00  1
2017-01-06 15:00:00  1
```

Comment: Nice! but what if I want to set to 0 the next 5 instead of the next  2?

Comment: That wasn't in the question ;-) You could chain the calls to `temp | temp.shift(1)` in a loop, for example.

Comment: what does the bar do

Comment: it's the element-wise OR operator for pandas DataFrames. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

ii = np.where(np.diff(df.index.values) != np.timedelta64(10,'m'))[0]
for i in ii:
    df['A'].values[i+1:i+3] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the index into a column and then create a new column `diff` using the `.diff()` that calculates the difference between two sequential entries of a column. The first result of the resulting column is a `NaN`. After that you can simply filter for rows where the `diff` is greater than the average. This way tou dont have to update your code if the time interval you are expecting between sequential indices changes.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 
date_range = pd.date_range(end=dt.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 15, 00), periods=10, freq='10Min')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)
df['A'] = 1
df.loc[:,'index'] = df.index.values.tolist()
df.loc[:, "diff"] = df['index'].diff()
print(df)
                     # A                index          diff
# 2017-01-06 13:30:00  1  1483709400000000000           NaN
# 2017-01-06 13:40:00  1  1483710000000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 13:50:00  1  1483710600000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:00:00  1  1483711200000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:10:00  1  1483711800000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:20:00  1  1483712400000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:30:00  1  1483713000000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:40:00  1  1483713600000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:50:00  1  1483714200000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 15:00:00  1  1483714800000000000  6.000000e+11

df_drop = df[df.index != dt.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 14, 00)]
df_drop.loc[:, "diff"] = df_drop['index'].diff()
print(df_drop)
                     # A                index          diff
# 2017-01-06 13:30:00  1  1483709400000000000           NaN
# 2017-01-06 13:40:00  1  1483710000000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 13:50:00  1  1483710600000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:10:00  1  1483711800000000000  1.200000e+12
# 2017-01-06 14:20:00  1  1483712400000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:30:00  1  1483713000000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:40:00  1  1483713600000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 14:50:00  1  1483714200000000000  6.000000e+11
# 2017-01-06 15:00:00  1  1483714800000000000  6.000000e+11
```

As you can see the fourth row of the `df_drop` dataframe has a `diff` value twice than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Using your repl.it, I just added a pandas column as a counter and added in a row for the missing data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 

date_range = pd.date_range(end=dt.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 15, 00), periods=10, freq='10Min')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range)
df['A'] = 1
df['B'] = list(range(len(df['A'])))

print(df)

# now we delete an specific row
df = df[df.index != dt.datetime(2017, 1, 6, 14, 00)]

for i in range(0, df['B'].iloc[-1]):
  if str(i) not in str(df['B'].iloc[i]):
    df2 = df.T
    insert_row = [0,0]
    df2.insert(i, 'missing', insert_row)  
    df = df2.T

print(df)
```